# Put image in drawable folder?

Tags: android, image

I put an image in my **res/drawable** folder, but when I clean and build my project, I receive the error message `R cannot be resolved`. I don't understand why this happens, what should I do?

Comment: your image name must be in case sensitive only small alphabets.....

Comment: name of image : h1.png, h2.png ... h30.png. What wrong ?

Comment: you said "I clear all image" can you provide the name of all images...? may be by screenshot of drawable folder

Comment: check console and problems in eclipse and paste that error here

Comment: What about to check **`Show View -> Error Log`**

Comment: `R cannot be resolved` occurs when there is certainly something wrong with xml files or drawable folder. I think you will get the error on any line on xml file or naming of images. check in console or problems or error log. There will be definitely some error addition to R can not be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following link:
http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html

> Note: Eclipse sometimes likes to add an "import android.R" statement at the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. This will cause your make to break. Look out for these erroneous import statements and delete them.

After removing the erroneous imports, delete your R.java file and try to clean and build the project again. If the problem still persists, post here.

Answer (score 1):

possible causes:

1. duplicate file names (across all drawables folders) . for example , is there a file named "h1.png" and also "h1.jpg" ?
2. bad files names . only letters allowed are lowercase english ones , and digits.
3. hidden files , like those of the OS . on windows , it's probably "Thumb.db" . either delete them , or delete & disable them. linux and mac also have such files , but with different names and usually start with "." .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image name is in **small latters** and in **res/drawable** folder.for how we add drawables in our project and supported images formats see docs [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: @user1465351 : edit your post with xml layout or relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are using android.R.drawable.your_image

Remove android.R from imports. use R.drawable.your_image

Answer (score 0):

For **Android Studio**:

1. Right click on res, new **Image Asset**
2. On **Asset type** choose **Action Bar and Tab Icons**
3. Choose the **image path**
4. Give your image a name in Resource name
5. Next->Finish

**The image will be saved in the /res/drawable folder!**